# Google cloud storage Blob.delete() does not create an archive even if versioning is enabled

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage Java Api to manage my bucket on Firebase.
i have activated the versioning with gsutil using this command :

```
gsutil versioning set on gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

After that i tried to delete some files with this java code :

```
com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket bucket = com.google.firebase.cloud.StorageClient.getInstance().bucket();
com.google.cloud.storage.Blob doc = bucket.get(documentPath);
log.info("Deleting document info => " + doc.toString());
doc.delete();
```

Log : Deleting document info => Blob{bucket=[BUCKET_NAME], name=test.pdf, generation=1545929848902866, size=196220, content-type=application/pdf, metadata=null}

This works, but it removes both the live and the archived version of the file.

Please how to just delete the live version and conserve the archived one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [versioning docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) they say :

> If you send a delete request with a generation that corresponds to the currently live object, Cloud Storage deletes the object without making an archived copy.

So, using `bucket.get('test.pdf');` returns the document and its generation number (you can see it in the log) even if i don't pass the generation number.

Solution :

```
@Bean
public FirebaseApp provideFirebaseOptions() throws IOException {
    log.info("INIT FIRBASE");
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(apiKey.getInputStream()))
            .setStorageBucket(bucketPath)
            .build();
    return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
}
// add this bean to provide StorageOptions service
@Bean
public Storage provideStorageService() throws IOException {
    log.info("INIT STORAGE");
    return StorageOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(ImplFirebaseTrampolines.getCredentials(provideFirebaseOptions()))
            .build()
            .getService();
}
```

Get and delete the doc :

```
//autowire storage bean
private final Storage storage;
public StorageService(Storage storage) {this.storage = storage;}
...
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(StorageClient.getInstance().bucket().getName(), documentPath);
log.info("Deleting document info => " + blobId.toString());
storage.delete(blobId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are turning versioning off. The correct command to [enable versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#enable)  is:

> gsutil versioning set **on** gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

Comment: Thanks @Omair but it is a typing error i just correct it.